# Spatial data analysis

Tags: econometrics, spatial, economics

I want to use a probit model on the probability of occurrence of a social problem in which one determinant will be location. For this, I have data on locations where the problem is occurring. What will be the best approach for considering the location factor in my model?

Comment: How do you measure location? Latitude and longitude? Place name (e.g., Dave’s house, Dave’s office, Dave’s favorite restaurant)? Something else?

Comment: What is your unit of observation?

Comment: I have the names of the district in which it's occuring. I want to find how the chances of the Social problem occurence will vary from one district to another.

Comment: Location here is qualitative as I have the district names where the problem is occurring.

Comment: So it’s a categorical variable?

Comment: Yes, if we assign a discrete number to each region.